# How to get the id of an inserted record in vertx using postgres sql client

Tags: java, postgresql, vert.x

I have a function that insert a single record into a PostgreSQL database. 
My question is how do i get the ID of the inserted record since the ID is auto generated 
This is the code

```
postgreSQLClient.getConnection(ar -> {
        if(ar.failed())
              LOGGER.error("saving message error:", ar.cause());
        else{
           SQLConnection conn = ar.result();
           conn.queryWithParams(insertStr.toString(), sqlParam, rs -> {
               conn.close();
               Constant.LOGGER.info("Save ID: " +rs.result());
           });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a RETURNING clause to your insert statement. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

This is from the vert.x documentation, see https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/java/

> Note about last inserted ids
>
> When inserting new rows into a table, you might want to retrieve auto-incremented ids from the database. The JDBC API usually lets you retrieve the last inserted id from a connection. If you use MySQL, it will work the way it does like the JDBC API. In PostgreSQL you can add the "RETURNING" clause to get the latest inserted ids. Use one of the query methods to get access to the returned columns.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code. I have an insert method which inserts a record. I want to get the id of inserted record or whole record with id.

Comment: ``INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
   RETURNING did;`` see the page that I linked in the postgresql docs.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this as;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117013/how-to-get-a-key-from-rxjava-insert-query-in-vert-x/54124379?noredirect=1#comment95080183_54124379