# how to get a key from rxjava insert query in vert.x

Tags: java, eclipse, rx-java2, vert.x

I have an insert method in my vert.x project written in rxjava style. In my method I run an insert query to insert the record in ms sql server. I want to get the auto incremented key of newly inserted record. How I can get it?

Here is my code.

```
 @Override
public Single<Record> save(Record record) {
    return new AsyncResultSingle<Record>(resultHandler -> {
        jdbcClient.rxGetConnection()
        .subscribe(connection -> {
            String sql = "INSERT into record (ani, template_id) values (?, ?)";
            JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(record.ani).add(record.templateId);
            connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params)
            .doAfterTerminate(connection::close)
            .subscribe(resultSet -> {
                List<JsonObject> rows = resultSet.getRows();
                //how I can get a key or Record object which has been inserted?
                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
            }, onError -> {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
            });
        }, onError -> {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: usually the key is autoincremented by means of database. This is not a question of java, eclipse, or vert.x.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I know the key is auto incremented and I can see it. My save method is inserting a new record with a unique id. The question is how I can get that id in rxjava style context.

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of

```
List<JsonObject> rows = resultSet.getRows();
```

you are looking for

```
List<JsonArray> results = resultSet.getResults();
```

EDIT: you already figured it out, but to correct my answer here: you also have to use `rxUpdateWithParams` instead of `rxQueryWithParams`.

Comment: the record is being inserted but I get Null in my resultSet. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

After I have changed

```
 connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params)
```

to

```
connection.rxUpdateWithParams(sql, params)
```

then, I am able to get the key as;

```
 JsonArray rows = resultSet.getKeys();
```

Thank you @taygetos for the hint.

Comment: I was just about to write this:)